# "Suggestions" or "recommendations" - which should be the main tag and which the synonym?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

About a week ago I suppose I (re)created the [suggestions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggestions) and [recommendations](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations) tags since we are now officially accepting questions of these types that meet our rigorous requirements.

As far as I'm concerned the two are synonyms so I went ahead and created both with the intention that they'd get merged later. Now it is later so which should be the main one?

**Keep in mind** guys I'm not asking an English Language & Usage question about whether these two words mean the same thing, I'm asking whether people are likely to use both of these words in similar kinds of on-topic questions.

Answer (score 5):

There IS actually a difference, albeit subtle.

Recommendations is where you are after answerers with personal experience that you can draw on to inform you about a place or event, etc.

Suggestions is more 'hey, I haven't done it myself, but have you tried xyz...?'

Given we are trying to draw on road warriors' experience on this site, recommendations should be the primary tag IF we are merging the two, as it's more what we're after, in my humble opinion.

Comment: In fact thinking about it more, I'm not convinced we even want suggestions anywhere... ;)

Comment: Well obviously two words are always at least slightly different like "rent" and "hire" but we're not talking about the words we're talking about how people are likely to tag questions. If people are likely to use pairs like "rent/hire" or "reccommendation/suggestion" then we make them tag synonyms because that's useful for the site, which is different to "linguistic" synonyms where the two have to be identical. Just take a look at how people use the words in questions: [Germany, Switzerland, Czech Rep - Suggestions for 3wk vacation](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2767/)

Answer (score 2):

My vote would be to keep [recommendations](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations) as main and [suggestions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suggestions) as synonym. I cannot explain why, but 'recommendation' has strong connotations of *asking* while 'suggestions' seem more suited for *telling*.

Comment: I think it's most sensible too but I'm a democratic kinda guy (-: